# 403 Forbidden Error when accessing _layouts folder

Tags: permissions, iis, aspx

I have inherited an application in which the Developer created a bunch of application pages (ASPX) which get deployed to the _layouts folder. The user is directed to these pages throughout the application like so:

```
http://<siteurl>/_layouts/15/ApplicationName/EditForm.aspx
```

However, not all users can access this. When we moved to UAT, users receive the following

> 403 forbidden

The only fix I have found is to give Everyone 'Full Control' on the Site in IIS. I don't think this is acceptable change for our Production environment.Is this an issue I can fix during deployment instead of making a manual change to Permissions? If not, will converting these Application pages to Visual Web Parts (ASCX) resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have, by some reason, wrong permission setup on C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ folder (I guess it is what you are referring "Site in IIS").

I checked my SharePoint farm. WSS_ADMIN_WPG, WSS_WPG and machine/users etc have been granted access. You may compare your permission setup with [Account permissions and security settings in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx).

For example, WSS_ADMIN_WPG would have modify permission on 
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15

Comment: They all have access but which level? Full Control? Read / Write / Modify?  It's funny because it works intermittently which would mean it may be hitting the other WFEs with different permissions

Comment: The link I quoted have mentioned their permission level needed. Notice I am talking about the NTFS permission on the WFE server not SharePoint permission. If you have a working WFE, you may just compare the permission setup on those folders.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell which versión of SharePoint do you have?

Quick answer, do these users have restricted access?? This configuración could make that pages not to be reached.